# Statically Compiled Oracle Client Drivers/Code

Tags: database, oracle, oracleclient

I'm looking to write a command-line program that can execute database scripts against an Oracle server, however the machine the program will be run on may not have an Oracle client installed on it.  I also don't want to rely on a language that requires a VM as there's no guarantee that the VM will be installed, so a language like C is preferable for this.  Is there a way that I can statically compile/build this program and not have to have the user install the Oracle client on that machine?  I'm trying to be as unobtrusive as possible.

Thanks.

Comment: "the machine the program will be run on may not have an Oracle client installed on it"?  How does this machine contact the database without a client?  What protocol are you going to use?

Comment: The current application uses Java, so it will use JDBC, however I don't want to rely on that in my installer since there may be a move to something else and I'd rather not have my code change if I can help it.  I forgot to add earlier, but this is for an installer, so to me the lowest common denominator is best.

Comment: What?  "I don't want to rely on that in my installer"?  Your application requires JDBC?  That requires a VM.  "I also don't want to rely on a language that requires a VM".  This is pretty well impossible to understand.  Please do not add comments.  Please UPDATE your question to clarify how you're magically going to use JDBC and not use a VM.

Comment: The application currently uses JDBC, however if we change to .NET or something else for whatever reason, I'd rather not change the code I use to run some database scripts for the installer.  This also makes this more reusable on other projects that may not use Java.  To me, it's not a good idea to have the installer for a program have to rely on a VM in order to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first guess was to use JDBC (type 4 driver) since you do not want a VM based language, it is out of the question.

SO, I think you should take a look at instant client

http://www.oracle.com/technology/tech/oci/instantclient/index.html

(thanks to google)

Comment: I swore I looked into this and didn't find it.

Anyway, thanks!  I'll give it a try.